# How to prevent the creation of an object in C++

Tags: c++, class

i'm learning how to make classes and i want to prevent my user from creating an object without providing a variable. The problem is that i don't know how to procede in order to do that. here's my code :

```
class KoalaNurse {
    public:
        int id; // the var that i need to provide in order to create a new object if it's not provided it wont create the object
        void giveDrug(std::string gato, SickKoala *patient) {
            patient->takeDrug(gato);
        }
        ~KoalaNurse() {
            std::cout << "Nurse " << id << ": Finally some rest !" << std::endl;
        }
};
```

ty for any help !

Comment: you need to read about constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your own constructor in order for the compiler not to create the default one.

```
KoalaNurse (int some_value)
{
 //your code
};
```

Another option is to use keyword `delete` in order to prevent creating default constructor:

```
KoalaNurse() = delete;
```

Comment: oh i see i didn't knew constructor worked like that ty !

Comment: i can't atm i need to wait 5 min

Answer (score 1):

In a situation like this you want to provide a user defined constructor.

```
class KoalaNurse {
public:
    explicit KoalaNurse( int id )
        : id_{ id }
    { }

private:
    int id_;
};

int main( ) {
    KoalaNurse nurse{ 10 };
}
```

With a constructor, in order to instantiate your `class` you have to provide an `id`.

Comment: Can you actually do `KoalaNurse nurse{10};` with an `explicit` constructor? I thought you'll need `KoalaNurse nurse(10);`.

Comment: @j6t No, it works as expected. The `explicit ctor` here will just prevent a `implicit` conversion. So, you wouldn't be able to pass an `int` to a function taking a `KoalaNurse` and have it `implicitly` converted to a `KoalaNurse`.